# An adjective meaning "full of potential"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Is there an adjective synonymous with having a lot of potential? Thank you!

Comment: "Highly charged", if you're talking about a Leyden jar.

Comment: "High voltage".

Comment: Why is this question considered off-topic?

Answer (score 10):

***Promising*** is often used to describe a person with potential.

Example: The *promising* young actor has been cast in the lead role.

"Promising", as defined in [MW-O](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promising):

> 1: full of promise: likely to succeed or to yield good results
>
> "a promising new medicine"